# SQL order by DESC not working

Tags: sql

I am doing a relatively small query with a sub query where I want to sort the sub query results in descending order. But in the result the sub query are not ordered in a descending order. Cannot see a reason why the ORDER BY does not work for me...

my query:

```
select 

customers.id,
customers.Name,
customers.Surname,

(select ifnull(sum(bets.amount),0)
from bets 
where customers.id=bets.customerId
and bets.date >'2014-06-01'
and bets.date <'2014-06-02'
order by bets.amount DESC
) as '1st_June',

(select ifnull(sum(bets.amount),0)
from bets 
where customers.id=bets.customerId
and bets.date >'2014-06-02'
and bets.date <'2014-06-03'
order by bets.amount DESC
) as '1st_June',


from customers

group by customers.id
```

I need to have a DESC order because I want to limit 100 so i get the top 100 values. Could someone suggest a way of doing this...?

Comment: Do you want the top 100 bets per customer?  If so what database are you using?

Comment: Or.. top 100 bet amount values... and/or top bets regardless of June 1st or June 2nd?

Comment: Your subqueries are sorted in a desc order. However, you cannot guarantee that the results will be displayed in the same order once the two quesries are joined. Why not to sort them by date and by amount at the end?

Answer (score 2):

Order By does not carry over past the group by like that.

This should give you what you're looking for instead:

```
SELECT customers.id
    ,customers.Name
    ,customers.Surname
    ,(
        SELECT ifnull(sum(bets.amount), 0)
        FROM bets
        WHERE customers.id = bets.customerId
            AND bets.date > '2014-06-01'
            AND bets.date < '2014-06-02'
        ) AS First_June
    ,(
        SELECT ifnull(sum(bets.amount), 0)
        FROM bets
        WHERE customers.id = bets.customerId
            AND bets.date > '2014-06-02'
            AND bets.date < '2014-06-03'
        ) AS Second_June
FROM customers
GROUP BY customers.id
ORDER BY First_June DESC
    ,Second_June DESC
LIMIT 100
```

- NOTE: (changed to "First_June" instead. beginning a column name with a number has issues in multiple SQL Servers, and you didn't specify which you're using. Oracle, MS SQL, MySql, Postgres, etc)

Comment: Note that arserbin3 changed the alias of your second subquery from `First_June` to `Second_June` and will order the list by the first subquery then the second subquery.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @Elias . I assumed that was a typo based on the date ranges, and fixed it.

Comment: It almost works but on occasions there are 0 values between the order

Comment: @user3669523 can you elaborate on that? i don't really follow what you're trying to say

Comment: @user3669523 What happens is it is sorting by the amounts in `First_June` then ordering by the amounts in `Second_June`. So it will grab all values for the second column and order them descending on the first column.